# How to apply a function to a certain column by name in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a columns that contain GPS coordinates. I want to convert the columns that are in degree seconds to degree decimals. For example, I have a 2 columns named "lat_sec" and "long_sec" that are formatted with values like 186780.8954N. I tried to write a function that saves the last character in the string as the direction, divide the number part of it to get the degree decimal, and then concatenate the two together to have the new format. I then tried to find the column by its name in the data frame and apply the function to it.

New to python and can't find other resources on this. I don't think I created my function properly. I have the word 'coordinate' in it because I did not know what to call the value that I am breaking down.
My data looks like this:

```
long_sec
635912.9277W
555057.2000W
581375.9850W
581166.2780W


df = pd.DataFrame(my_array)

def convertDec(coordinate):
    decimal = float(coordinate[:-1]/3600)
    direction = coordinate[-1:]
    return str(decimal) + str(direction)

df['lat_sec'] = df['lat_sec'].apply(lambda x: x.convertDec())

My error looks like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 44, in <module>
    df['lat_sec'] = df['lat_sec'].apply(lambda x: x.convertDec())
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2917, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2604, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 129, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'lat_sec'
```

Comment: Well, it seems like you have no column named `lat_sec`. Try and `print(df.head())` to see how your data frame looks

Comment: Always try to include a minimal example of any data/input with your question so we can copy/paste from the question to test and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @lostCode I got a similar error as above when I tried that

Comment: @Itay I printed it and I do have a column with that name

Comment: @Itay   File "apt_code.py", line 44, in <module>
    df['lat_sec'] = df['lat_sec'].map(convertDec)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2917, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

Comment: @wwii I posted it above

Comment: Your question now shows only one column named `long_sec`

Answer (score 0):

By doing `float(coordinate[:-1]/3600)` you are dividing `str` by `int` which is not possible, what you can do is convert the `str` into `float` than divide it by integer `3600` which gives you `float` output.

Second you are not using `apply` properly and there is no `lat_sec` column to which you are applying your function

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['635912.9277W','555057.2000W','581375.9850W','581166.2780W'],columns=['long_sec'])

#function creation
def convertDec(coordinate):
    decimal = float(coordinate[:-1])/3600
    direction = coordinate[-1:]
    return str(decimal) + str(direction)

#if you just want to update the existing column 
df['long_sec'] = df.apply(lambda row: convertDec(row['long_sec']), axis=1)

#if you want to create a new column, just change to the name that you want
df['lat_sec'] = df.apply(lambda row: convertDec(row['long_sec']), axis=1) 

#OUTPUT
    long_sec
0   176.64247991666667W
1   154.18255555555555W
2   161.49332916666665W
3   161.43507722222225W
```

if you don't want output in float but in integer just change `float(coordinate[:-1])/3600` to `int(float(coordinate[:-1])/3600)`

Answer (score -1):

In your code above, inside `convertDec` method, there is also an error in :

```
decimal = float(coordinate[:-1]/3600)
```

You need to convert the `coordinate` to float first before divide it with 3600.

So, your code above should look like this :

```
import pandas as pd

# Your example dataset
dictCoordinates = {
    "long_sec" : ["111111.1111W", "222222.2222W", "333333.3333W", "444444.4444W"],
    "lat_sec"  : ["555555.5555N", "666666.6666N", "777777.7777N", "888888.8888N"]
}

# Insert your dataset into Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = dictCoordinates)

# Your conversion method here
def convertDec(coordinate):
    decimal = float(coordinate[:-1]) / 3600 # Eliminate last character, then convert to float, then divide it with 3600
    decimal = format(decimal, ".4f") # To make sure the output has 4 digits after decimal point
    direction = coordinate[-1] # Extract direction (N or W) from content
    return str(decimal) + direction # Return your desired output

# Do the conversion for your "long_sec"
df["long_sec"] = df.apply(lambda x : convertDec(x["long_sec"]), axis = 1)

# Do the conversion for your "lat_sec"
df["lat_sec"] = df.apply(lambda x : convertDec(x["lat_sec"]), axis = 1)

print(df)
```

That's it. Hope this helps.

Comment: You just copied the given answer.

Comment: I have my own answer and I have my own code. Just because my code has the same variable names, same function name, and the same algorithm, it doesn't mean I copied the given answer.